# Robot verification (form filling bot) without CAPTCHA: isTrusted vs HTML grabbing

Tags: javascript, forms, captcha

I have a doubt about the use of isTrusted and I'd like to share it. How can I deny that a server side script grabs my HTML source code and makes a POST HTTP call to my action URL? In this way, the isTrusted property can be easily passed over. Unfortunately, I can't use a CAPTCHA or reCAPTCHA.

I have a really sample form like this:

```
<form id="mod" action="otherPage.php" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" name="yourName">
<input type="hidden" name="noCSRF" value="eweifwo23-423dad13123.ljk9879">
<input type="submit" id="sender">
</form>
```

And a simple script like this:

```
document.getElementById("mod").submit=function(){ return false; };

document.getElementById("sender").addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    var replicant=true;

    if ("isTrusted" in event)
    {
        if (event.isTrusted)
        {
            replicant=false;
        }
        
        if (!replicant) 
        {
            alert("you are a human");
            //XMLHttpRequest to action URL
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("YOU ARE A REPLICANT!!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("nothing to do!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If an automated program behaves like a human with a browser *you can't*.

You are dependant on tracking the differences between humans and robots. A CAPTCHA (which you've rejected) is a common and low effort (on your side of things anyway) to detect this different. Robots are very bad at filling out CAPTCHAs.

Other approaches involve testing things like frequency of requests (robots can be more frequent or have more consistent intervals between requests) from a source, similarities of requests (robots may be posting the same spam message to multiple places across a website) and so on.

Your code example uses client-side JS, but that can be bypassed easily. You need server-side testing for this.

Comment: Ok I've got it. Thanks.